# How is digital property protected by the fourth amendment?

Tags: united-states, internet, search-and-seizure

I recently watched a documentary called Deep Web. It featured the drug market on the deep web and the arrest and trial of Ross Ulbricht. He was indicted on charges for drug trafficking over the deep web among others. The FBI hacked into Ulbricht's computer to find evidence against him, which the defendants claimed as unconstitutional since it was a search and seizure of property without a warrant. According to the documentary, the FBI simply dismissed the claims.

The movie was clearly biased towards Ulbricht, so I didn't get the full story and I suspect some of the information was somewhat skewed. But it raised a good point, the FBI did hack into Ulbricht's computer, which is his private property, without a warrant. On what basis would this type of action by the FBI be justified/legal?

Comment: Here's a good read: https://www.wired.com/2014/10/feds-silk-road-hack-legal/ - But essentially they claimed a warrant was not necessary because it was blatantly criminal. Don't forget that the Fourth Amendment only protects you from *unreasonable* search and seizure. It's perfectly reasonable to search and seize when it's blatantly obvious that criminal activity is taking place.